# The complexity of $A^{k \cdot log_{x} (n)}$ is exponential?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

The complexity of $A^{k \cdot log_{x}(n)}$ is exponential? ($k$ and $x$ is constants, $A$ is defined constant base, $n$ is the size of the task).

It is in a class of polynomial complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is polynomial complexity, because

$$A^{k \log_x n} = A^{k \lg n / \lg x} = (2^{\lg A})^{k \lg n / \lg x} = (2^{\lg n})^{k \lg A / \lg x} = n^{k \lg A / \lg x}$$

and $k \lg A / \lg x$ is a fixed constant.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. For any logarithm base?